# Editable form in APEX for different roles

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle-apex, roles

I am trying to implement the following process in APEX.
The following is the case:

1. A student creates a form, here the responsible first and second supervisor for the thesis can be selected.
2. When the form is submitted, the responsible first and second supervisors  only see  the final papers which are assigned to them .
3. They can click on a final paper to edit it.
4. When they click edit, they see the student's created form, but can only edit the fields that are tied to their roles.

I created an interactive report page for the primary supervisor. Here he can see all  final papers assigned to him which are listed in an interactive report.

I then linked the thesis ID to the student's created thesis form.
I created some fields and used an authorization scheme so that only the first supervisor can see and edit these fields.

I am not sure if this is the common procedure in apex or if there is not a better way to implement it.
The general idea is that different users can gradually edit and add things to the form.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you have an actual **programming problem**? Or are you just asking for advice on ways to implement this workflow?

Comment: First of all, I would like to know whether this is the right way to implement such process. So that I use the same form for different roles but depending on the role different functionalities are provided (or different fields are displayed). As an example, if the first supervisor wants to edit the request , then he must not be allowed to change the set fields from the student, but only has the possibility to confirm or reject the request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" answer to this question.

It sounds like you have multiple users with different *roles* in your application and they're allowed to do different things. It sounds like you have a *Student* role and a *Supervisor* role already. (Don't forget to consider that a user may have both roles, depending on their situation. I may be a Student for my thesis, but a Supervisor for someone else's.)

You want an input form for the Student and a review form for the Supervisor and the fields will largely overlap. You could use one Apex page for each, or a single page that changes depending on the mode it's used in. You also need a way to tell the page that it's being operated in one mode vs the other. Personally, I go for the second approach when it's feasible.

This means you will use the **Read Only** attribute for the different page items depending on whether the user is a Student or Supervisor. You may also want to use the **Server Side Condition** attribute to remove some page items or regions entirely.

For example, the Student may enter a Title attribute so that needs to be read-write, but the Supervisor only needs to see it, so that will be read only. The supervisor will need Approve and Reject options, but the Student should not see those at all.